# Ajax does not want to send me a PUT query

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

I want to send to the controller a new e-mail given by the user using ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: '/changeEmail?',
        data: {
            email: function() {
                return $('#email').val();
            }
        },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log('function');
            if(result === true) {
                console.log("true");
            } else {
                console.log("false");
            }
        }
    });
```

To the controller (sample code)

```
@PutMapping("/changeEmail")
public boolean changeEmail(
        @RequestParam("email") String email
) {
    System.out.println("email: " + email);

    return true;
}
```

However, when dispatching, the browser console throws me out

```
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 PUT http://localhost:8080/signIn net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Ajax is trying to send data to a completely different address than the one I provided in ajax.
In Ajax I gave

```
/changeEmail
```

And he is trying to send me on

```
/signIn
```

What this is about?

Comment: Open the developer tools network tab and see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues here. Firstly remove the `?` from the end of the URL. jQuery will add it automatically, if required.

Secondly don't provide a function in the object you set to `data`. Give the value directly. Also, `result` will be a string, so your comparison to a boolean will not work as you expect. To be safe while testing, it's best to just log the response directly. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'PUT',
  url: '/changeEmail?',
  data: { 
    email: $('#email').val();
  },
  success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

Lastly, if your request is being redirected from `/changeEmail` to `/signIn`, then it sounds like you will need to authenticate the request. Exactly how you do that varies from one API to another, so I'd suggest you check their documentation.